# How to add array parameters on Postman client?

Tags: postman

I am using Postman client for Mac. I am trying to use Buffer API to update my Buffer account's schedules. The API endpoint refers to usage of these parameters:

```
POST Data
    schedules[0][days][]=mon&
    schedules[0][days][]=tue&
    schedules[0][days][]=thu&
    schedules[0][times][]=12:45&
    schedules[0][times][]=15:30&
    schedules[0][times][]=17:43&
```

But, when I use on Postman, or Insomnia Mac client, it does not update my Buffer account. It shows up as success on the API request response. But, the Buffer schedules are not updated.

What is the right way to insert array parameters in Postman?

Comment: can you show your request's body ?

Comment: did you solve this?